# Find string in expl3 case function and store result in integer variable

Tags: expl3, expansion, token

If I pass a time zone (e.g. CEST) to the function `\__mildate_parse_timezone:n`, the function `\__mildate_timezone_abbrev:n` should find the associated time zone in UTC as an integer (for future calculations) and the function `\__mildate_timezone_nato:n` should output the associated NATO code as a string.

The function `\__mildate_timezone_abbrev:n` finds the matching string, but does not store it in the variable `\__mildate_timezone_int`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \__mildate_timezone_int
\tl_new:N  \__mildate_timezone_tl

% Time zone NATO code according to UTC
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mildate_timezone_nato:n #1 {
    \tl_set:Nn \__mildate_timezone_tl {
    \int_case:nnF { #1 }
      {
        { -12 } { Y }    
        { -11 } { X }    
        { -10 } { W }
        { -9 }  { V }   
        { -8 }  { U }   
        { -7 }  { T }
        { -6 }  { S }    
        { -5 }  { R }   
        { -4 }  { Q }   
        { -3 }  { P }   
        { -2 }  { O } 
        { -1 }  { N } 
        { 0 }   { Z }  
        { 1 }   { A }    
        { 2 }   { B }    
        { 3 }   { C }
        { 4 }   { D }   
        { 5 }   { E }   
        { 6 }   { F }
        { 7 }   { G }    
        { 8 }   { H }   
        { 9 }   { I }   
        { 10 }  { K }
        { 11 }  { L }       
        { 12 }  { M } 
      } { ??? }
   }
}

% Abbrev. timezones and their UTC
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mildate_timezone_abbrev:n #1 {
    % I guess here is the problem!!!
    \int_set:Nn \__mildate_timezone_int {
    \str_case:nnF { #1 }
      {
        { PST }  { -8 }  % Pacific Standard Time
        { PDT }  { -7 }  % Pacific Daylight Time
        { CST }  { -6 }  % Central Standard Time
        { MDT }  { -6 }  % Mountain Daylight Time
        { CDT }  { -5 }  % Central Daylight Time
        { EST }  { -5 }  % Eastern Standard Time
        { GMT }  { 0 }   % Greenwich Mean Time
        { UTC }  { 0 }   % Universal Time Coordinated
        { WET }  { 0 }   % Western European Time
        { CET }  { +1 }  % Central European Time
        { WEST } { +1 }  % Western European Summer Time
        { CEST } { +2 }  % Central European Summer Time
        { EET }  { +2 }  % Eastern European Time
        { EEST } { +3 }  % Eastern European Summer Time
        { TRT }  { +3 }  % Turkey Time
      } { 13 }
   }
}

\seq_new:N \l__mildate_timezone_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mildate_parse_timezone:n #1 {
    \IfValueT {#1} {
        \regex_match:nnT { \A [a-zA-Z]{2,5} \Z } { #1 }
            { 
                \regex_extract_once:nnN { \A ([a-zA-Z]{2,5}) \Z } { #1 } \__mildate_timezone_seq
                \__mildate_timezone_abbrev:n { \seq_item:Nn \__mildate_timezone_seq {2} }
                \__mildate_timezone_nato:n { \__mildate_timezone_int }
            }
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\timezone {m} {
    \__mildate_parse_timezone:n { #1 }
    \__mildate_timezone_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \timezone{CEST}
\end{document}
```

I need someone to point me in the right direction

Thanks, Alex

Comment: You definitely need to expand the argument in `\__mildate_timezone_abbrev:n { \seq_item:Nn \__mildate_timezone_seq {2} }` with either an `x, e or f` type. If you don't, `\str_case:nnF { #1 }` compares literally `\seq_item:Nn \__mildate_timezone_seq {2}` (and not its content) with PDT PST etc. You could also use `\str_case_e:nn`

Comment: Do you really need to do the `\regex_match` thing? I don't see why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added the necessary expansions so `\str_case:nnF` compares the correct things. Also changes `\tl_set:Nn` to `\tl_set:Nx` in `\__mildate_timezone_nato:n`.

You should change `\regex_match:nnT ... \regex_extract_once:nnN` to `\regex_extract_once:nnNT`. Else you are evaluating the regex twice and regex latex3 is already quite slow.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \__mildate_timezone_int
\tl_new:N  \__mildate_timezone_tl

% Time zone NATO code according to UTC
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mildate_timezone_nato:n #1 {
    \tl_set:Nx \__mildate_timezone_tl {
        \int_case:nnF { #1 }
        {
            { -12 } { Y }    
            { -11 } { X }    
            { -10 } { W }
            { -9 }  { V }   
            { -8 }  { U }   
            { -7 }  { T }
            { -6 }  { S }    
            { -5 }  { R }   
            { -4 }  { Q }   
            { -3 }  { P }   
            { -2 }  { O } 
            { -1 }  { N } 
            { 0 }   { Z }  
            { 1 }   { A }    
            { 2 }   { B }    
            { 3 }   { C }
            { 4 }   { D }   
            { 5 }   { E }   
            { 6 }   { F }
            { 7 }   { G }    
            { 8 }   { H }   
            { 9 }   { I }   
            { 10 }  { K }
            { 11 }  { L }       
            { 12 }  { M } 
        } { ??? }
    }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mildate_timezone_nato:n { V }

% Abbrev. timezones and their UTC
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mildate_timezone_abbrev:n #1 {
    % I guess here is the problem!!!
    \int_set:Nn \__mildate_timezone_int {
        \str_case:nnF { #1 }
        {
            { PST }  { -8 }  % Pacific Standard Time
            { PDT }  { -7 }  % Pacific Daylight Time
            { CST }  { -6 }  % Central Standard Time
            { MDT }  { -6 }  % Mountain Daylight Time
            { CDT }  { -5 }  % Central Daylight Time
            { EST }  { -5 }  % Eastern Standard Time
            { GMT }  { 0 }   % Greenwich Mean Time
            { UTC }  { 0 }   % Universal Time Coordinated
            { WET }  { 0 }   % Western European Time
            { CET }  { +1 }  % Central European Time
            { WEST } { +1 }  % Western European Summer Time
            { CEST } { +2 }  % Central European Summer Time
            { EET }  { +2 }  % Eastern European Time
            { EEST } { +3 }  % Eastern European Summer Time
            { TRT }  { +3 }  % Turkey Time
        } { 13 }
    }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mildate_timezone_abbrev:n { x }

\seq_new:N \l__mildate_timezone_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mildate_parse_timezone:n #1 {
    \IfValueT {#1} {
        \regex_match:nnT { \A [a-zA-Z]{2,5} \Z } { #1 }
        { 
            \regex_extract_once:nnN { \A ([a-zA-Z]{2,5}) \Z } { #1 } \__mildate_timezone_seq
            \__mildate_timezone_abbrev:x { \seq_item:Nn \__mildate_timezone_seq {2} }
            \__mildate_timezone_nato:V \__mildate_timezone_int
        }
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand\timezone {m} {
    \__mildate_parse_timezone:n { #1 }
    \__mildate_timezone_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \timezone{CEST}
\end{document}
```

EDIT:
I would probably write this instead. I don't know exactly why you need to use regex

```
\NewDocumentCommand\timezone {m} {
    \IfValueT{#1} % Can be removed
    { \__mildate_parse_timezone:n { #1 } } % can be removed
    % \__mildate_parse_timezone:n { #1 } % And use this instead
    \tl_use:N \__mildate_timezone_tl
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mildate_parse_timezone:n #1
{
    \__mildate_timezone_abbrev:x {#1}
    \__mildate_timezone_nato:V \__mildate_timezone_int
}
```

Comment: Also `\IfValueT{#1}` is redundant

Comment: True, I kept it there because he might want an error message.

Comment: Finished my milDate package and pushed it to github.
https://github.com/alex-1974/milDate